# Percorrer objetos com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, objetos

Preciso listar objetos e recorri a seguinte função que é em jQuery. Existe uma alternativa a essa apenas em JavaScript?

```
$.each(object, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Você precisa rotacionar objetos é isso?

Comment: @PauloRoberto é sim..

Comment: @Paulo, rejeitei sua sugestão de edição porque "Rotacionar" não é o que está acontecendo, não tem nenhum objeto na tela sendo rotacionado (90graus ou 180 ou qualquer outro valor)... certamente é uma confusão linguística, acredito que [sugestão do Edilson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/44288) é a correta: "Percorrer" (eu não tinha conseguido pensar na palavra adequada para aquele `$.each`) -ou então "Iterar" como diz o Sergio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basicamente é isto:

```js
var objeto = [ 1, 2 ];
for (var chave in objeto) console.log(objeto[chave]);
```

Pode ser que queira melhorar se estiver pegando membros indesejáveis:

```js
var objeto = [ 1, 2 ];
for (var chave in objeto) if (objeto.hasOwnProperty(chave)) console.log(objeto[chave]);
```

Embora tecnicamente para ter a mesma semântica teria que fazer isto:

```js
var objeto = [ 1, 2 ];
objeto.forEach(function(valor, indice) {
    console.log(valor);
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/For.js).

Funciona em todos os navegadores modernos, mas nem todos usam um moderno, use com cuidado.

Comment: A primeira solução me ajudou bastante..

Answer (score 8):

Esse código só por sí não roda nada.
<sub>(ou será que queres dizer "iterar" e eu que falo português de portugal penso que te referes a rotação de eixo?)</sub>.

Para iterar uma array podes usar o `.forEach()` nativo ou um ciclo for se precisares de dar suporte ao IE8.

```
object.forEach(function(value, index){
    console.log(value);
    // fazer mais algo com o valor
});
```

ou para browsers mais antigos:

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
    var value = object[i];
    var index = i;   // desnecessário, mas coloquei para clarificar
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Eu também me perco quando falaz algo diferente.. Mas o que eu quiz dizer e deixei mal expressado na pergunta é que seria necessário rodar a array de objetos, não sei bem o que significa iterar, rotação de eixo... Perdão a leiguice...

Comment: @Elaine É ás vezes a lingua atrapalha :) se queres percorrer essa array e usar cada elemento da array então é "iterar" e é o que a minha resposta aponta.

Comment: http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/iterar. No nosso contexto costuma ser "fazer um laço passando por cada elemento do objeto".

Answer (score 1):

ecmascrip6 :

```
 array.forEach((item)=>{
  console.log(item);                        
 });
```

Comment: Sempre é interessante explicar minimamente o que seu trecho de código faz. :)